# how to replace while read LINE

Tags: shell, while-loop, logfile

I wrote a script to print specific days of a log file ! the script work properly , but I wrote the loop part with **while read line**  and the log file contains more than 150000 items ! the script wants to read it line by line and it takes hours !so, the while should be changed in some way ! I know about for I in {1..N} but I want something better that work for any log file .

what do you suggest ?

Comment: Is perl an option? You could try parsing it with a regular expression tool. It will in any case take a lot of time though.

Comment: no in bash shell not Perl ! I don't know what is regular expression ! i'm beginner

Comment: Reading 150,000 lines with bash does not take hours. The content of the while body is the cause of the slowness you report.

Comment: but when I have while read line I always have problem ! I should press enter for each line to be read

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to show us what you are doing. Please edit your posting to include smallest subset of `while` loop code that illustrates your problem.  Also please show exact text of any errors or warning msgs.

Per your comment '... I should press enter for each line to be read'. You are definitely doing something wrong. Reading each line should be automatic. Here is a basic outline of processing files with bash.

Would you consider using awk? I can post better solutions with that standard tool.

```
 inputFiles="${@}"
 cat "${inputFiles}"\
 | while read line ; do
     case ${line} in
        2[0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-1][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]* ) 
            # matched date
             print ${line}
        ;;
        * )
            # you'll need to add other reg-expes here to extract data you want
        ;;
      esac
 done
```

You may have to remove the dbl-quotes on `${inputFiles}`.

The purpose of using `cat ${inputfiles | while read line ...` is to allow processing any files you list on the cmdline.

Have you tried using `grep` to look thru your logfiles?

```
 date1='2011-09-11' ; date2='2011-09-12'; date3='2011-09-13'
 grep "${date1}|${date2}|${date3}" *.logFiles | grep -i error
```

You could also use the date1... as a case target in the while loop above.

```
 case ${line} in
   ${date1}*|${date2}*|${date3}* )
      echo $line
   ;;
 esac
```

You may get away with removing the '`*`'s above OR if the date is NOT the first element in the line, you may need to add '`*`' in front of each `${dateN}`.

Or if you're keeping your logfiles zipped up,

```
 gunzip -c ${zippedLogFiles_gz) | grep "${date1}|${date2}|${date3}" | grep -i error
```

is often a good place to start (and only unzips your files in place (just sending the uncompressed output into the pipe)).

P.S. as you appear to be a new user, if you get an answer that helps you please remember to mark it as accepted, and/or give it a + (or -) as a useful answer.